Ubuntu 22.04 used a huge amount of traffic after booting
I have a second laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 installed, which I did not boot under Ubuntu for Apx. 1.5 month.
Today I booted it and logged in, then wanted to check the activity monitor. Normally I see there is some 10-20MB of traffic after startup, but this time the used data amount was growing fast and has grown until 3Gb (received traffic). In parallel, I have started NetHogs to check which process generates this activity and have found out that snapd and apt/method/https takes the whole bandwidth (100mbit channel). Looks like Ubuntu downloaded some kind of updates for apt and snap, but, is it normal that the amount of data it downloads at startup is so big? (like 3gb)?
